# Reuse inserted id

Tags: sql, postgresql, insert

Say I have a table Contracts:

```
  id  |  name | document_url  
-----------------------------
```

Where the documentUrl is automatically generated/uploaded to S3 and has the following structure:

`https://s3-bucket.aws.com/${id}.pdf`

My question is how I can insert that in a single `INSERT` query.

```
INSERT INTO contracts(name, document_url)
VALUES('bob', ${process.env.S3_BUCKET}.aws.com/????.pdf}
```

I am calling this code from inside a NodeJS server, and the bucket is stored as an environment variable outside the database on a per server basis. Is there some way to get the id of the row currently being inserted, or do I have to insert returning, and then update within a transaction?

Comment: Is it right, the expression `${process.env.S3_BUCKET}` will be evaluated and `${id}`not?

Comment: yeah. So ${process.env.S3_BUCKET} is a javascript interpolation.

id is a variable that does not yet exist when the js runs as the postgres connection has not yet run the sql

Comment: I guess you could use a sequence (https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/sql-createsequence.html) but really just bite the bullet and use an insert and then an update.

Comment: Build the url at query time, or at least the id part.

Comment: What about `INSERT INTO contracts(name, document_url)
VALUES('bob', ${process.env.S3_BUCKET}.aws.com/????.pdf} RETURNING id` ? See https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/dml-returning.html

Comment: That's what I'm currently doing:

`const {rows: [{id: id}]} = pool.query('INSERT INTO contracts(name) VALUES('bob') RETURNING id;')
pool.query(\`UPDATE contracts SETdocument_url=${process.env.S3_BUCKET}.aws.com/{id}.pdf} WHERE id=$1;\`,[id])`

I would very much like to do it in a single statement

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps your table can skip trying to store `document_url` and look more like:

```
id  |  name | s3_bucket  
-----------------------
```

Then query with:

```
SELECT name
      ,'https://' || s3_bucket  || '/' || id || '.pdf' AS document_url
  FROM contracts
```

Creating a view based on the query will encapsulate the composition so that those querying don't need to know how to paste it together:

```
CREATE VIEW contract_documents AS
SELECT name
      ,'https://' || s3_bucket  || '/' || id || '.pdf' AS document_url
  FROM contracts
```

then externally:

```
SELECT name, document_url
  FROM contract_documents
```